# Sprite animation won't work on unity, what shall I do?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, sprite

I have an issue. My sprite won't animate in unity. Other parameters, like position, will change, but sprites won't. I've added a screenshot below.[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV7eB.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You have a nullreference exception where something called PlayableOutput is null. It is obviously possible that an error can cause some crucial script to stop executing. That's all I can say from that image.